# forEach repeats functions

Tags: javascript, html, function, foreach

```js
 document.querySelectorAll('.item').forEach(item => item.addEventListener (
    'click', function () {
        console.log('Hello World!')
    }
))
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <article class="item">3</article>
  <article class="item">2</article>
  <article class="item">1</article>
</div>
```

As you can see I have container with three child element. I want to display `'Hello World!'` when one of the article is pressed.

And when I press article that has 3 as content, console displays this:

[image: forEach function is repeated 3 times]

When I press second article:

[image: forEach function is repeated 2 times]

And when I press last article it displays only one 'Hello World!' in the console (how it must be). So it seems that this function is being repeated. And how to fix it?

Comment: FYI, IDs should be unique. This markup is not valid. Use classes, or select all `article`s.

Comment: oh I use classes I just changed here, Ima change it really quick

Comment: I'm not seeing a problem. Those number should just be the number of times you clicked. Instead of repeating the output it adds a number beside the output.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as not reproducible. If Asker thinks it is reproducible they should prove it with a runnable snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is actually doing what you want but perhaps you're interpreting the number next to each console log incorrectly.

The number next to the console log entry indicates how many times that particular message has been logged within some interval of time.

If you change each of your listeners to also log data specific to each element, it will become more clear that each element's listener is only firing once.

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>StackOverflow Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <article class="item">3</article>
            <article class="item">2</article>
            <article class="item">1</article>
        </div>
        <script>
            window.onload = function () {
                document.querySelectorAll(".item").forEach((item, index) =>
                    item.addEventListener("click", function () {
                        console.log("Hello World!", index);
                    })
                );
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```